# Calculator is not working. New to coding

Tags: java, android, calculator

I'm new to android coding, and have too little experience in programming.
I wanted to try to make a Calculator. I thought its going to be easy but, I'm stuck.
Basically you enter into an EditText the number then press "+#*/" then enter another number and then press Enter. But somehow as soon as I press + or else it crashes. Can someone tell me what is wrong? Oh and the logcat says :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
at com.industriesoi.taschenrechner.Calc.calcPlus(Calc.java:87)
```

but I dont know what to change there..

Here's my code:

```
package com.industriesoi.taschenrechner;

import com.industriesoi.taschenrechner.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class Calc extends Activity {

    // INITIAL
    EditText etZahl;
    TextView tvErgebnis;

    double zahl1=0;
    double zahl2=0;
    char operation = '0';
    double ergebnis=0;


    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;



// ONCREATE HERE
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        etZahl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etZahl);
        tvErgebnis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvErgebnis);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.

    }

    public void calcPlus(View view){
        String stringZahl1 = etZahl.getText().toString();
        zahl1 = Double.parseDouble(stringZahl1);
        operation = '+';
        etZahl.setText("");
    }

    public void calcMinus(View view){
        String stringZahl1 = etZahl.getText().toString();
        zahl1 = Double.parseDouble(stringZahl1);
        operation = '-';
        etZahl.setText("");
    }

    public void calcMultiply(View view){
        String stringZahl1 = etZahl.getText().toString();
        zahl1 = Double.parseDouble(stringZahl1);
        operation = '*';
        etZahl.setText("");
    }

    public void calcDivide(View view){
        String stringZahl1 = etZahl.getText().toString();
        zahl1 = Double.parseDouble(stringZahl1);
        operation = '/';
        etZahl.setText("");
    }

    public void calcEnter(View view){
        //first operate;
        switch(operation){
            case '+':
                ergebnis=zahl1+zahl2;
                break;
            case '-':
                ergebnis=zahl1-zahl2;
                break;
            case '*':
                ergebnis=zahl1*zahl2;
                break;
            case '/':
                ergebnis=zahl1/zahl2;
                break;
            default:
                ergebnis=0;
        }
        //then change text;
        String doubleToString = Double.toString(ergebnis);
        tvErgebnis.setText(doubleToString);
    }
}
```

_
Oh and if you could give me some advice on coding that would be nice too. Like how could I improve this calculator, even if there is little to it?

Comment: where are your listeners?? you have build the methods but you dont seem to call it anywhere

Comment: Defined in XML, as error message shows that the functions are invoked

Comment: What you are basically doing in this calculator is for example: "nothing + nothing".  This means that you are not reading the values of the numbers entered correctly

Comment: Your `switch` is totally wrong

Comment: @DerGolem what is wrong with the switch? The only thing I see wrong with that method is that it takes a `View` parameter that is never used.

Comment: Why is it nothing+nothing? At least it should be 0+0 like I made both variables 0 at the beginning. And the problem is that the crash happens when it tries to get the EditText into stringZahl1. So I don't even come that far.

Are all of those View view 's unneccessary in this? I just saw it somewhere for onclick methods so I copied it.

Comment: @AlexC. you're right, the View is required if you've set the onClick method in XML. In my apps, I don't set them in XML but in the code, so I didn't know you need it.

Comment: **1** the switch acceps an **integer**, not a character. **2** that switch should react to the different **view id** (which is an integer) : `switch(view.getID()){ case R.id.btnPlus{ ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try moving these lines:

```
etZahl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etZahl);
tvErgebnis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvErgebnis);
```

after this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc);
```

in the onCreate method.
Without setContentView, you can't get the view by id.

Comment: I think this will be correct. Just some advice (I see this is your first answer) avoid any comments that sound like you are not confident, it gives you answer a bit of uncertainty, which doesn't sound good. Be confident in your answers, people take them more seriously. If you make a mistake, it can always be edited or deleted.

Comment: You were right now I can press the buttons without crashing. Although the calculation itself needs to be fixed. I hope I can do that.

Comment: @AlexC. To make the calculator work, you need to also setup some listeners for the button. Otherwise on press the button, android don't know what need to execute.

Comment: @xwhyLikeThis But I added android:onClick to the buttons in the xml file. So that part should work right, or? Because the problem now is the calculation doesnt work right. I type 5 then press + then 7 then press Enter. It says 10.

Comment: @xwhyLikeThis of course. Some people (myself included occasionally) might stop reading after seeing 'I can't comment' because usually it's not followed by a good answer. ;P

Comment: @AlexC. as long as you've used the correct method names, it should. I have seen people set them in XML too. Does it work, or no?

Comment: Well it doesnt work the way it should. Like I type 5 then press + then type 7 and press Enter it says 10 in the output.

Comment: @AlexC. For value zahl2, how do you get it? I think you need "zahl2=Double.parseDouble(etZahl.getText().toString())" in calcEnter method.

Comment: Yup saw that and added it.
Now there was another error in the methods.
        String stringZahl1 = etZahl.getText().toString();
        zahl1 = Double.parseDouble(stringZahl1);

I changed it to something like you showed me:

        zahl1 = Double.parseDouble(etZahl.getText().toString());

Now that works. What is different about it? Whats wrong with my version?

Comment: @AlexC. Sorry I did not make it clear. It has no difference. What I mean is in the "calcEnter" method where you do "zahl1+zahl2", the zahl1 value is stored when you press "+" button, however, the zahl2 should be got when you press the Enter button. So you need to add "zahl2=Double.parseDouble(etZahl.getText().toString())" to get the second value before the swift statement.

Comment: Yeah that works fine. 
Is there a way to keep it from crashing when pressing + two times without any number input?

Comment: @AlexC. The reason why it crash is because the empty string can't be parse to double. In this case, maybe you can just set the editText value to "0" by default to solve the issue. You can also check the zahl1 or zahl2 value to make sure it is not empty string before parsing to double.

Comment: Alright it's kinda messy with the 0 always appearing there but well at least it works now. Next I would like to know more about this View view thing I dont really know when to use, or what it means. Do you have something for beginners?